# How to stop Speech Recognition (Dictation) in Apple Watch when the user stops speaking?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have succesfully implemented native speech recognition (Dictation) in Apple Watch (WatchOS 2.1, iOS 9.2.1) basically I used this code, with an empty "menu options array":

```
func launchDictation(){
        self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions([], allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain, completion:{
            (results) -> Void in
                let aResult = results?[0] as? String
                if(!(aResult == nil)){
                    print(aResult)
                    print("SHORT ASR COMPLETED")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        // Update UI
                    }
                }//end if
            })//end show voice menu
    }
```

As it is... the user taps a "Speak button", then a view pops up (showing the detected words as the user speaks and a nice small volume graph). Right now, the user has to speak, and tap "Done" to complete speech recognition. If a phrase is detected but "Done" is not tapped a "dictation failed" will eventually appear onscreen. Does somebody know how to implement some listener or delegate that detects when the end of the Dictation process a few seconds after the user has stopped speaking?

Comment: "a nice small volume graph": did you do it your self or by the dictation API?

Comment: The dictation API shows it by default, although I have read in SO that the amazon app apparently shows a colored graph like the one used by Siri @user523234

Comment: @Josh, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope, the user has to stop voice recognition by tapping. It is so ugly! @PierreCharpentier

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Josh. Do you know if we can stop dictation programmatically after a fix time ? ( stop dictation after 10 seconds for example)

Comment: You can set a timer that starts inside the onBeginningOfSpeech() method of the recognizer, that does recognizer.cancel() or recognizer.stop after X seconds. @PierreCharpentier

Comment: Hmm.. It's a solution for Android and not WatchOS, isn't it ?

Comment: Omg, sorry for that, I am having huge ASR problems with android right now and I am starting to lose my wits!! Sorry. As far as I know, there is no way to stop speech recognition in WatchOS programmatically. @PierreCharpentier