# Is it possible to skip Done button click while using presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions for voice input in applewatch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am using following code for voice input for applewatch.

```
[self presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:nil allowedInputMode:WKTextInputModePlain completion:^(NSArray *results) {
        NSLog(@"results: %@", results);
    }];
```

It shows voice input screen with Done and cancel button. After speak you have to click Done button. I want to skip Done button click like siri working.After few seconds it automatically accept the input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268552/how-to-stop-speech-recognition-dictation-in-apple-watch-when-the-user-stops-sp

Comment: Did you ever figure out this? Running into the same issue