# How to start and stop dictation in Apple Watch witout pressing button

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, dictation

I wrote code to use dictation on my apple watch. I used presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions without suggestions to directly start dictation.

But, I have two problem :

- I want to start dictation when my app starts. For this, I call my function in the willActivate method but with this, just a waiting image appears in my screen, not my first page with dictation.
- I want to stop dictation without press "Done" button. I don't know if it's possible and how can I make this.

There is my code :

```
func dictation(){
        self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions([], allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain, completion:{
            (results) -> Void in
                 //myCode
            })
    }
override func willActivate(){
   super.willActivate()
   dictation()
}
```

Do you have solutions ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268552/how-to-stop-speech-recognition-dictation-in-apple-watch-when-the-user-stops-sp

Comment: What happens if you post the call to dictation after a short delay, or in didAppear?

Comment: @Feldur I print log when I begin and finish a function. There are my logs : "start init
end init
start awakeWithContext
end awakeWithContext
start willactivate
end willactivate
start didAppear
start dictation
end didAppear" and I always have my waiting screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help @Feldur

I tried with delay and it seems to work

There is my code :

```
override init(){
    super.init()
    print("start init")
    let seconds = 1.0
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
    let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.dictation()
    })
    print("end init")
}
```

There are my logs :

```
start init
end init
start awakeWithContext
end awakeWithContext
start willactivate
end willactivate
start didAppear
end didAppear
start dictation
```

My screen appears and after, my dictation starts.

Do you have an idea for stop dictation when user stops speaking ?

Comment: You'll need to process the audio stream looking for silence (absence of energy)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is API or native component to do it ?

Comment: I don't. Maybe in AV?  If you google on power spectra, you can find the math.

Comment: Ok. I ill search more in this way. If somebody has another idea

Comment: I have been able to detect silences (to be exact: periods of time where volume is below the threshold) with a library called EZAudio (also allows you to make an animated graph of the voice waveform), unfortunately, it is now discontinued, but you can still use it. The problem is that I could only use it for iPhone apps, because WatchOS complains that EZAudio architecture is not supported, and I have now idea how to recompile it.